# Redirect to created page, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The problem: user creates post and then after submit he have to be redirected to his created post. How can I realize this. I use

```
$id = $post->id;
```

`return Redirect::to('post')`, here I need to put the id of the new page. How can I do this ?

Comment: That depends.. how does the desired route/url look like?

Comment: Route::get('/post/{id}/','PostController@getPost');

Comment: url looks like: site.com/post/78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options on how to redirect to the URL with the post id.

The simplest one would be to just append the id:

```
return Redirect::to('post/'.$id);
```

You could also redirect to the route matching your controller action:

```
return Redirect::action('PostController@getPost', array($id));
```

And probably the most elegant one, giving your route a name and using that:

```
Route::get('/post/{id}/', array('as' => 'view-post', 'uses' => 'PostController@getPost'));

return Redirect::route('view-post', array($id));
```

You can find a reference of all ways to make a redirect **[here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects)**

Comment: Great answer. Highly recommend using the last method.

Comment: @ColinSchoen Thanks, I'd use that one too. Especially since you can use the route name everywhere... Checking for the current route, generating links, etc etc

Comment: Fantastic. Have a nice day.